# How to call setState twice if the second relies on the first?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

How do I achieve this simple logic in react if the second setState hook depends on thee first one to change first?
In this example, the first setState value doesn't update fast enough before running the second setState.
I have tried putting the second one in a timeout, as well as putting it inside a callback function of the first. Didn't work out.
The useEffect might solve this issue but in this particular instance I would need to call useEffect only in the first one and not every time there is a state change. Let me know your thoughts.

```js
function blah(arg) {
    if (condition) {
        setState(arg)
    }
    setState(state + 1)
}
```

Comment: Why do you need to do this? You might be looking for a solution when the actual problem can be solved in a different way

Comment: @evolutionxbox agree, you may state your actual problem.

Comment: Do both changes happen as part of a lifecycle event or a DOM event handler? If so, both changes will be batched together.

Comment: the question is simple, how do I achieve this simple logic in react (in the way I intuitively intended for it to work, since this logic does not work)
so any solution that achieves this would be great

Comment: _"this simple logic"_ what makes you think it's simple?

Comment: its simple in concept. 
if (condition) { var = value }
var++

Answer (score 4, accepted):

React's State isn't meant to work as a variable. When you call `setState`, you are simply telling the code what value it is supposed to use in the next rendering of the component. It will never set the value immediatly.

If you need it to behave as a variable, just use variables and call `setState` a single time at the end.

```
function blah(arg) {
    let aux = state;
    if (condition) {
        aux = arg;
    }
    setState(aux + 1);
}
```

Comment: Okay, but this only works if you're passing to setState the new value that's already been computed.   What if you want setState to modify the state based on the previous call.    Based on this answer, you'd have mutate the state twice, once in the component as part of the processing, and once later when setState is called.

Comment: @zumalifeguard I don't think I have fully understood your question. Could you elaborate in a proper SO question? Feel free to tag me there or link your question below, and I will do my best to answer you. What I can preliminarily say is that the expected behavior of setState is absolutely meant to mutate the state and trigger a re-render of its component. If you don't wish for this behavior, remember there are multiple ways to store values in React. State is the most popular but is not a Jack of all trades. You can look into other strategies like React's ref or even a simple variable.

Comment: I'll do that when I get a chance.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

you need to use the useEffect hook :

```
const [state, setState] = useState();

useEffect(() => {
    // get executed  whenever state is changed
}, [state])


function blah(arg) {
    if (condition) {
        setState(arg)
    }
}
```

Comment: but i am changing state in other places too and i dont want the useEffect to be called , only in this specific instance

Comment: if so you can delay the second setState using setTimeout

Answer (score 0):

First Load up on the function

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
```

Then

```
const [ListValue, setListValue] = useState([]);
  
useEffect(() => {
    console.log(ListValue)
}, [])


function blah(arg) {
    if (condition) {
        setListValue(arg)
    }
}
```